# Convergent Divergent nozzle

Tags: vacuum

What is the formula to calculate pressure at the nozzle outlet, if small port is given the nozzle throat where vacuum is created?

Answer (score 1):

Read the article about the deLaval nozzle in Wikipedia: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Laval_nozzle

It has figures, explanations and the formula you want. There is too much to include in an answer here.